# chrome.history.search() doesn't return all history

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser-history

So for the past few weeks I've been trying to make myself a chrome extension that auto deletes history, I thought I was about finished, but I then realized that the chrome.history.search() doesn't return all of the history, only some and I can't figure out why certain bits of history get deleted and some don't. I currently have

```
`chrome.storage.sync.get({ // Retrieving the stored array of words
    list: []
},
function(data) {
    for (i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++) {
        let searchString = data.list[i].toString(); //String that is searched for
        chrome.history.search({ // History search function
          text: searchString, // String to search for
          startTime: 2678400000,
          maxResults: 5000,
      }, checkHistory)
  }
});`
```

and my callback function is

```
`function checkHistory(historyItems) {
    for (let item of historyItems) { // Deleting items that were found in the search
        chrome.history.deleteUrl({
            url: item.url
        });
    }
}`
```

My goal is so that if I search for "Google" for example, it'll delete all searches with the sub-string "Google" in them. I'm 100% sure that the list isn't the issue as it prints just fine, One thing I've noticed is that when I attempt to delete, it always deletes everything older than 2-3 days with the sub-string, I thought I'd just put it out there I'm not sure if it means anything.
I would appreciate any insight on what the issue could be. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe its because of the start time, find how chrome calculates its time. If it doesnt work then try the API

```
chrome.history.deleteRange(object range, function callback)
```